# SQL Error: ORA-01861: literal does not match format string 01861 being thrown on SQL select of a NUMBER field

Tags: oracle

In referencing a view in an Oracle database, we have some columns that contain decimal days which are produced from calculations like the one below:

```
 CASE
  WHEN
     (
        date_field_a is null 
        OR date_field_b IS NULL
     )
  THEN
     -9999 
  ELSE
      to_number(to_char(to_date(date_field_a, 'DD-MON-YYYY') - to_date(date_field_b, 'DD-MON-YYYY')),'9999.9999')
```

Which results in a NUMBER column containing `NULL` values, `-9999`, or `decimal digit` values.  The calculation seems to be performed correctly, and throws no errors during the creation.

However, when pulling this view into crystal reports or another program, this field and several others like it, cause this error:

> ```
> SQL Error: ORA-01861: literal does not match format string 01861
> ```

Which, doesn't make sense to me since these fields are registering as NUMBER fields.

What is causing this error?

**Edit:**

`date_field_a` and `date_field_b` are datetime data types.

Comment: in oracle `dateA - dateB` is already a number, why convert to string and back again?

Comment: I think one or more of your rows have a bad "string-that-looks-like-a-date" in them, and it is the to_date() that is failing. Re-run your sql without the `to_number(to_char(` to confirm? I also think something is awry in your understanding, because `SELECT * FROM table_with_decimal_column` will not throw this error. Is it the case that you're selecting from a view that is calculating this value from a base table that has bad date data?

Comment: What are the data types of date_field_a  and date_field_b?

Comment: @CaiusJard, yes, you are correct, I am hitting a view

Answer (score 0):

Like Caius said, your underlying table probably has some data which are not formatted the way you expect. If that's the case, you can query the table to try to find the problem rows, e.g.

```
select *
from YOUR_TABLE
where not regexp_like(date_field_a, '[0-9][0-9]?-[a-zA-Z]{3}-[0-9]{4}')
  or not regexp_like(date_field_b, '[0-9][0-9]?-[a-zA-Z]{3}-[0-9]{4}');
```

*note, this simple regexp won't catch if you have a misspelled month. But that seems unlikely.

Another alternative is that, like Wernfried suggested, if your `date_field_a` is actually a `DATE` data type, then your problem is likely due to implicit conversion - you're relying on the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` environment variable being identical on all client machines, which is impossible to guarantee.

If your columns are `DATE`, don't wrap them in a `TO_DATE()` call - it will do an implicit conversion and *actually* call `to_date(to_char(date_field_a, NLS_DATE_FORMAT), 'DD-MON-YYYY')` - and you will get unpredictable results.

Answer (score 0):

### Description

When you encounter an `ORA-01861` error, the following error message will appear:

### Cause

You tried to enter a literal with a format string, but the length of the format string was not the same length as the literal.

### Resolution

Re-enter the literal so that it matches the format string.

For example, if you tried to execute the following statement:

```
SELECT TO_DATE('20041308','yyyy/mm/dd') FROM dual;
```

You would receive the following error message:

[image: Oracle PLSQL]

You could correct the SQL statement as follows:

```
SELECT TO_DATE('2004/08/13','yyyy/mm/dd') FROM dual;
```

As a general rule, if you are using the `TO_DATE` function, `TO_TIMESTAMP` function, `TO_CHAR` function, and similar functions, make sure that the literal that you provide matches the format string that you've specified.

Answer (score 0):

Per the edit to your question:

> Edit: date_field_a and date_field_b are datetime data types.

Then you should ditch all this conversion code and go with:

```
CREATE VIEW x AS
SELECT
   ...
   COALESCE(date_field_a - date_field_b, -9999) as yournumber,
   ...
FROM
   yourtable
```

If the dates are dates, then you get a number of days and fractions of days between the two. If two dates are exactly 36 hours apart you get 1.5 (days)

If one of the dates is null, you get null. In that case you want -9999, and that's what the coalesce is for

> ```
> select sysdate - TO_DATE('2001-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd') from dual
> ```
>
> ```
> | SYSDATE-TO_DATE('2001-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') |
> | -----------------------------------------: |
> |  6848.718715277777777777777777777777777778 |
> ```

> ```
> select sysdate - CAST(null as date) from dual
> ```
>
> ```
> | SYSDATE-CAST(NULLASDATE) |
> | -----------------------: |
> |                     null |
> ```

> ```
> select COALESCE(sysdate - CAST(null as date), -9999) from dual
> ```
>
> ```
> | COALESCE(SYSDATE-CAST(NULLASDATE),-9999) |
> | ---------------------------------------: |
> |                                    -9999 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5773eb3a7bd0baf7df65f75db6adbe18)*